# DB2 For i: Convert Char YYMMDD to Date

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a CHAR_Date column containing date values in the format 'YYMMDD'.

I would like to do date arithmetic so I need to convert it into a Date data type. The problem is that the Char_Date also contains Blanks.

How do I cast the CHAR_Date to a DATE_Date column, with valid values?

Comment: The only answer to date apparently inferred "contains Blanks" means that the value for the Char_Date column may have values that are blank.  Given that sole answer has not been accepted, perhaps the "contains Blanks" intends to imply something different; perhaps providing some examples would be helpful -- or perhaps the answer is acceptable, and thus can be accepted.?  Or perhaps what was offered failing to give DATE data type is an issue, or the unstated release does not enable a one-argumet TIMESTAMP scalar; so perhaps instead: DATE(TO_DATE(NULLIF(CHAR_DATE,''),'YYMMDD'))

Comment: @CRPence "TO_DATE()" is not a Valid DB2 for i ("db2400") function.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscale.htm

Answer marked as accepted. Query already signed-off and in production.

Comment: Despite not being visible\searchable on that page, TO_DATE is valid; see [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm) "**Notes** **Syntax alternatives**: TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP are synonyms for TIMESTAMP_FORMAT."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 case when CHAR_Date = '' then TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01') 
                          else TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR_Date, 'YYMMDD') 
                   end 
  as DATE_Date 

 FROM TABLE_Data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function TIMESTAMP_FORMAT

TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('990205' , 'YYMMDD')

And if you want a date:

DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('990205' , 'YYMMDD'))